# Understanding that a simplicial complex is a PL manifold via links

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, pl-manifolds

Suppose $X$ it a simplicial complex homeomorphic to a topological $n$-manifold. Suppose we know that the link of each $k$-simplex $\Delta^k$ is *homeomorphic* (as a topological space) to the sphere $S^{n-k-1}$.

**Question.** Is it true that the manifold $X$ is a PL manifold? (i.e. it is locally PL homeomorphic to balls in $\mathbb R^n$)

If so is there a reference for such a statement? Would you advise some nice source of PL manifolds?

**Disclosure.** This question is my attempt to understand Remark (i) that comes after Theorem 2 in the following paper of Sullivan and Sibenmann. I hope that I understood it correctly: [http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~dennis/publications/PDF/DS-pub-0041.pdf](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Edennis/publications/PDF/DS-pub-0041.pdf)

**PS** I suspect that the answer to the question might be unknown because it is not known whether $S^4$ has an exotic smooth (or PL) structure. If it has, one can triangulate such an exotic $S^4$ and take a cone over it. It feels to me that such a cone will not be a PL manifold, though I am not sure...

Comment: When I say the link of $\Delta^k$ is homeomorphic to a sphere I don't mean PL homeomorphic but just homeomorphic as a topological space. And I require the condition for all $k$. I don't see why this is equivalent to being PL by definition. If this is so, could you please give a reference to such definition?

Comment: is this related to Tits buildings of spherical type?

Comment: @DimaPasechnik I doubt strongly that there can be a connection. Tits buildings are even not topological manifolds, as far as I understand.

Comment: I don't think this suffices.  You also need that the transition maps are PL equivalences.  i.e.  the links of any two incident simplices in $X$ intersect, so there is a transition function between the two charts.  This transition function needs to be a PL automorphism, as well.   That said, sometimes the situation simplifies, for example in dimension 4.  In this case you need only restrict to the $k=0$ case, and you can avoid discussion of transition functions since $S^3$ has only the one PL structure.

Comment: Ryan, I asked this question trying to understand Remark (i) that comes after Theorem 2 in a paper of Sullivan and Siebenmann. I think that this remark is equivalent to what I wrote modulo smooth Poincare conjecture in dimension 4. Would you agree?

Comment: For $n=4$, yes it is a smooth manifold. But I think invoking the 4-dimensional Poincare conjecture is overkill, since all you really need is uniqueness of PL structures on the 3-sphere.

Comment: aren't flag varieties of projective spaces examples of buildings?

Comment: Ryan, how would you construct a counterexample to the question? (if you believe it exists). I say the following: if there is an exotic smooth $S^4$, triangulate it, and take a cone over it. I don't see why this is a PL manifold, but it satisfies the conditions of the question. I am interested in all dimensions, not only dimension $4$ though

Comment: Dima, I don't know unfortunately, never worked with spherical buildings, just heard talks about them and they did not look at all like manifolds. Do you have un understandable reference where it is mentioned that flag varieties are examples of spherical buildings? (just out of curiosity)

Comment: The cone on an exotic PL sphere is a counterexample because it is **not** a PL manifold. The link and cone are inverse operations. The link of cone point is the base of the cone. In this case, that is a topological sphere that is not a PL sphere. Thus the cone is not a PL manifold, because the definition of a PL manifold is that all the links are PL spheres. But it is the cone on a topological sphere, so it is a topological disk.

Comment: Thanks Ben! This is what I thought. But I have a follow up question. Suppose by some miracle I know additionally that all the links of codimension 5 simplexes are non-exotic 4 spheres. Is then the answer to my question positive? Do you know any reference buy the way?

Comment: Rourke and Sanderson is the reference for fundamentals. This is a weird hypothesis and I doubt anyone wrote about it. Assuming the generalized Poincare conjecture is a clean hypothesis, but I doubt anyone wrote about it in more detail than your source, which calls it an exercise. I think that your weaker hypothesis is sufficient. To use it inductively, you would need to know that a double link is a single link; that is, the link of a simplex in the link of a simplex in X is just the link of a simplex in X: $L(a,L(b,X))=L(a*b,X)$, where $a*b$ is the join, the simplex with the union of verticies